# Text not showing when for() is executing

Tags: java, javafx

Below is the example demonstrates that the text ("A","B","C" and "testing in progress...") for each `Label` and `TextArea` will not showing when a for() is executing. It will show simultaneously once for() is finished!

Any solution to overcome this?

```
public class Test1Controller {

    @FXML
    private Label l1;
    @FXML
    private Label l2;
    @FXML
    private Label l3;
    @FXML
    private TextArea info;
    @FXML
    private Button B1;


    @FXML
    void B1_runing(ActionEvent event) 
    {

        l1.setText("A");
        l2.setText("B");
        l3.setText("C");
        info.appendText("testing in progress...\n");            
        B1.setDisable(true);

        for( int i=0; i<800; i++ )
        {
            for( int x=0; x<10000000; x++ );
        }

        info.appendText("end...\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't you effectively have a spin lock on the UI thread?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JLabel changing values through setText but not updating on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822070/jlabel-changing-values-through-settext-but-not-updating-on-screen)

Comment: Read about [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm). "_Implementing long-running tasks on the JavaFX Application thread inevitably makes an application UI unresponsive_"

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're running an intensive operation on the UI thread. The text area can't redraw itself until you're finished because all of this is happening on a single thread.

It's not usually a problem to do simple calculations on the UI thread, but your loops go for 8 billion iterations.

The way to avoid this situation is to push any intensive operations onto another thread. There are multiple ways to do that, which will depend on your use case. In your example, your loop doesn't really do anything so you could simply replace your loops with this:

```
new Thread( ()->{
    // Send the lambda to the Application (UI) thread
    Platform.runLater(()->info.appendText("testing in progress...\n"));

    for( int i=0; i<800; i++ )
    {
         for( int x=0; x<10000000; x++ );
    }

    // Send the lambda to the Application (UI) thread
    Platform.runLater(()->info.appendText("end...\n"));
}).start();
```

Usage of `Thread` like this is kind of discouraged in modern Java, but it demonstrates the point. A better solutions might involve [`Future`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) or [`ExecutorService`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Comment: The intention for this example is to make it simple for discussion and to find a solution to display text of "A" , "B", "C" and  "testing in progress..." to USER before execute a for() and then show the last text of "end..." in sequencing way, perhaps a step by step way. Thread method will not help as it won't run in sequence way.

Comment: It still runs in sequence, just on a separate thread that doesn't block the UI.

Comment: @Michael well, it depends, the UI will respond so you could launch anything else during the thread execution. So there is some concurrency to manage. But nothing prevent to simple block every event from the UI during the execution of this (simple solution ;) ).

Comment: @AxelH Yes, I didn't say it was easy. He said "thread method will not help", but using threads is the *only* thing you can do in this situation. Well, that and not loop 8 billion times for no reason.

Comment: @Michael, I agree, it's just the "_it still runs in sequence_" that bother me at the time, it could be understood as, the UI will update but the code will wait the end of the thread. So I prefered to add a keyword here, concurrency ;) FYI : business logic on the UI Thread should be really short time consuming, see [What is the maximum tolerable time the UI thread is blocked?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/42688) for some interesting idea.

Comment: @AxelH I meant the content of the thread is still sequential, perhaps I wasn't clear enough. Yep, I thought I covered that when I said "... do simple calculations on the UI thread". Interesting answer, though.

Comment: You can't call `info.appendText(...)` from a background thread.

Comment: Since JavaFX is used, maybe it is better to use Platform.runLater().

Comment: @James_D Right. Fixed.

Comment: The Platform.runLater() will help but it is not stable! It failed to execute runLater if you try to run the program again and again (for testing program reliablitiy).Also it seems like it won't solve what if you add a line eg. l1.setText("some more..") after the runLater() infor.appenText("end...\n).

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what you're talking about.